# How to add an array of hashes into a csv file?

Tags: ruby, csv, hash, append

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864876/9826060) and it fits me nicely, i transformed it into this one:

```
def write_in_file(file_name, hash)
    column_names = hash.first.keys
    s=CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        hash.each do |x|
            csv << x.values
        end
    end
File.write("#{file_name}.csv", s)
end
```

This is how my array of hashes looks:

```
[
  {:Name => "John", :Age => 26, :Country => America},
  {:Name => "Ivan", :Age => 34, :Country => Russia},
  {:Name => "Pablo", :Age => 20, :Country => Columbia}
]
```

But the problem is that every time I call this method - it rewrites whole file. How to change it, if i want to save this headers and add new information every iteration?

Comment: Open the file in _append_ mode (`mode: 'a'`) and skip writing the header row on subsequent writes.

Comment: Write "mode: 'a'" instead of 's'? And how to skip writing the header in subsequent writes?

Comment: No, `s` is your content. It's `File.write("#{file_name}.csv", s, mode: 'a')`, consult the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/IO.html#write-method) for details. For the headers: you could initially check whether the file exists. If not you write the header row. If it exists, you assume that the headers are there and just write the values.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem! :)

Comment: @gurman "a" is short for "append".

Comment: @gurman To skip the headers you can use: `csv << column_names unless File.exist?("#{file_name}.csv")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append to an existing file by using `mode: 'a'`: (see [open modes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode))

```
File.write("#{file_name}.csv", s, mode: 'a')
```

To write the headers only on the first run, you could check whether the file exists. In addition, you should use a fixed header and fetch the hash values in that specific order, e.g.:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << %w[Name Age Country] unless File.exist?("#{file_name}.csv")

  hash.each do |x|
    csv << x.values_at(:Name, :Age, :Country)
  end
end

File.write("#{file_name}.csv", s, mode: 'a')
```

There's also [`CSV.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#open-method) which creates the file for you:

```
CSV.open("#{file_name}.csv", 'a') do |csv|
  csv << %w[Name Age Country] if csv.stat.zero?

  hash.each do |x|
    csv << x.values_at(:Name, :Age, :Country)
  end
end
```

Since the file will always exist when the block gets executed, the header check needs to be changed: `csv.stat` returns the file's [`File::Stat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/File/Stat.html) and [`zero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/File/Stat.html#zero-3F-method) determines whether the file is empty.